# Import numbers with leading zeroes from excel with ACE.OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a program in which the user selects an excel spreadsheet. The program then reads from that excel file with OLE.DB and stores that data into a DataTable. My problem is when i import barcodes from the excel spreadsheet with leading zeroes, they get trimmed. My columns are formatted as text. Below is my code:

```
    public DataTable GetExcelInfo(string filepath)
    {
        DataTable datatab = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text\\";
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Format([F1], \"#\"), [F2], [F3] FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
                adapt.Fill(datatab);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorReporting.File(e, "GetExcelInfo");
        }
        return datatab;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use `OleDbDataReader` instead of `OleDbDataAdapter`? That way you can control contents of every column when reading from excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both `Nino` comment and `Jacek Cz` answer were helpful to solving my problem I made this answer to sum it up.

-- In general numbers with leading zeroes in excel should start with an apostrophe `'`.

-- The same rule for fields similar to date, like invoice number `11/16/03`.

-- Apostrophe can be added via many ways, try (disclaimer! not tested) OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Format("'"+[F1], \"#\"), [F2], [F3] FROM [Sheet1$]", conn); or replace (with regular expression) in XLS file.

-- An easier way of handling the data retrieved from the file is using `OleDbDataReader` instead of `OleDbDataAdapter` where you can specify for example what data type you are retrieving.

Answer (score 1):

Export to excell file (Open Office formats too) for fields having sense string, but starting with digits, should start with apostrophe `'`.

`'0001230056709`

The same rule for fields similar to date, like invoice number `11/16/03`

Long 'fake numbers' can be not only cut from beginning , but rounded as double etc ...

Comment: Yeah found many people suggesting that but unfortunately our clients get their spreadsheet from a supplier and they are not allowed to modify it at all. I ended up using what Nino suggested but thanks for the replies

Comment: apostrophe can be added via many way, try (disclaimer! not tested) OleDbDataAdapter adapt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Format("'"+[F1], \"#\"), [F2], [F3] FROM [Sheet1$]", conn); or replace (with regular expression) in XLS file ... I do many times such correction in place of provider

Comment: I tried doing that before posting here and it didnt work, though there is a good change I made a mistake in the syntax though.